# How should I manage .Net and Visual Studio versions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Microsoft appears not to have consdiered the problems in managing Visual Studio projects when multiple versions of .Net or multiple versions of Visual Studio are in use.  Can anyone recommend ways to manage these intelligently?

We have quite a bit of code that was written using Visual Studio 2008.  If we want to update the code and choose to use VS 2012, VS does a one-way upgrade, and we can't use VS 2008 on those projects any more.  We do have at least one machine running Windows Server 2003, and while it's not normally used for development, we do sometimes use it, and we can't install VS 2012 on it.

Worse, we have customers with computers of various operating systems, so we can't count on having a specific version of .Net.  It would be nice to be able to select the .Net version in the project configuration, but we can't.  The first tab of the Projects screen contains the .Net version selection, and that screen does not change with different project configurations.

I can't even really use the same source code files, because there are differences in available libraries between .Net 4.5 and earlier versions.  The one that comes to mind is System.Threading.Tasks, which is included by default in .Net 4.5 files, and which isn't available in earlier .Net versions.  And I don't know of any way to use compiler constants to differentiate between operating systems or .Net versions in C# as is (or at least used to be) possible in C++.

Comment: To clarify your question: Are you saying that for the same project, you want to be able to change the .Net version used based on what's available on the local machine that it's being edited on?

Comment: Please consider splitting your question into more concrete once - I see 3 separate questions at this point: "how to use the same project with VS2008 and VS2012+ at the same time" (you can't), "how to specify multiple target frameworks in same project" and "how to specify conditional compilation symbols in the project" (multiple duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this same issue over the past few years and my solution has varied depending on the project.  My optimum solution, and the one I use 90% of the time, is to migrate the project to the latest version of Visual Studio.  For projects where that is not possible, I create virtual machines to hold the visual studio install that I need.  Then whenever I need to work in the legacy project, I fire up VMware workstation and put it into full screen mode.

Not sure this would work for you, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed side-by-side (I have 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015 preview all installed on the same development machine). If you have a project in which some developers cannot use the latest version of VS, then you will just need to use the older version. Though with 2012-2015 you can round-trip (i.e., there is no upgrade when you open a solution with a later version of VS).

For the .NET versions, you can target earlier versions of .NET from later versions of VS. Here you need to decide what is the minimum level of .NET that you plan to target for a given platform (expect your customers to have installed). The later versions of .NET add additional functionality so you need to decide if you want to use those features and thereby require your customer to upgrade .NET or if you will make do without those features. One option to consider is creating a simple setup program for application deployment that contains the requisite .NET boost strap installer. The next version of the framework will supposedly allow for deploying framework libraries in you application directory, which might mitigate this issue of what version of .NET the customer has installed on the system.